Does Blood Curse of the Fallen Puppet provoke an attack of opportunity
At level 1, Blood Hunters get to pick a Blood Curse, and one option is the

Blood Curse of the Fallen Puppet
When a creature you can see within 30 feet of you drops to 0 hit points, you can use your reaction to instill that creature with a final act of aggression. The creature immediately makes one weapon attack against a target of your choice within its range.
Blockquote

Like all Blood Curses, this curse can be amplified (by spending your own HP) to gain an additional effect, in this case:

Amplify. You can first cause the cursed creature to move up to half its speed, and you grant a bonus to its attack roll equal to your Hemocraft modifier (minimum of +1).

My Question would be:
Are we moving the creature, or is the creature moving on its own?
If we are moving the creature, then the cursed creature would not be provoking an attack of opportunity:

You can avoid provoking an opportunity attack by taking the Disengage action. You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction. For example, you don’t provoke an opportunity attack if an explosion hurls you out of a foe’s reach or if gravity causes you to fall past an enemy.

The case where this matters is that a Blood Hunter could use this curse not on an enemy but on an ally to get them out of harms way when they drop to 0 HP. But if this would provoke an AoO, then the ally would be at risk of taking 2 failed death saves from an auto-crit if the AoO hits.
Sidenote: This is different than Dissonant Whispers, since even if we assume that the caster of this spell moves the target, the latter creature cannot avoid the AoO as it has to use its reaction, so the cited part above does not apply and the AoO would be triggered either way.

You don't move the creature, you cause it to move

Amplify. You can first cause the cursed creature to move up to half its speed,

You cause the creature to move, that is, the creature is moving by itself (under its own power), you just cause it to do so. It is thus using its movement, not being moved, and suffers opportunity attacks.
You can also see this from the fact that the movement is using the creature's speed. The language used for forced movement is different; for example thunderwave says the creature "is pushed", and the distance moved is independent of the creature's speed.
